# YouTube Upload Gamma Shift

Tags: youtube, prores, gamma

I've just finished a music video in Resolve and exported it as Mov/Prores422HQ. It looks correct when played back in Quicktime and in VLC, however when I upload to YouTube, there is a huge gamma shift and the blacks look washed out.

YouTube on the left, Quicktime on the right:

[image]

What can I do to mitigate this gamma shift?

Comment: The short answer is to ensure that your output's color encoding is Rec 709 & limited range. Not familiar with Resolve, so don't know where to adjust it. This is not a gamma shift. HD video and sRGB have similar transfer functions (gamma). It's an issue of color range and possibly color primaries. Some players assume the defaults I mention at the top, even if the file is tagged otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I had set my Timeline Colorspace to sRGB.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get an acceptable result by exporting as Mov/Prores 4444 and a Timeline Colorspace of Rec 709 Gamma 2.2.